# Why derivatives of the matrix annihilating polynomial must be equal to zero?

Tags: matrices, functions

In order to get some background in functions of matrices I'm studying Chapter
5 of Gantmacher "The theory of matrices" book.
We have two arbitrary polynomials g($\lambda),
    $h($\lambda)$ such that g(A) = h(A), formula (2).

Don't understand formula (4) p. 95:

why $d'(\lambda_k) = 0$?

It's quite clear why
$d(\lambda_k) = 0$
because $d(\lambda_k)$ consists of multipliers, one of them is the minimal
polynomial, and $\lambda_k$ is one of his roots. But why the same must be hold
for derivatives of $d(\lambda_k)$?

For example  A =

$\begin{matrix}
3 & -3 & 2 \\
-1 & 5 & -2 \\
-1 & 3 & 0
\end{matrix}$

$\lambda_1$ = 2, $\lambda_2$ = 4

g($\lambda$) = $\lambda^3$ - 6$\lambda^2$ + 8$\lambda$

h($\lambda$) = $\lambda^4$ - 6$\lambda^3$ + 8$\lambda^2$

both are annihilating.

d($\lambda$) = g($\lambda$) - h($\lambda$) = -$\lambda^4$ + 7$\lambda^3$ - 14$\lambda^2$ + 8$\lambda$

d($\lambda_1$) = d(2) = 0.

d'($\lambda$) = -4$\lambda^3$ + 21$\lambda^2$ - 28$\lambda$ + 8

d'($\lambda_1$) = d'(2) = -4*2^3 + 21*2^2 - 28*2 + 8 $\neq$ 0.

So why formula (4) doesn't hold in my case?

**Reference**
Felix Ruvimovich Gantmacher (2000)[1977] "*The Theory of Matrices. Volume One*", AMS Chelsea Publishing, pp. x+374.

**EDIT:**

$\psi(\lambda) = (\lambda - \lambda_1)^m1(\lambda - \lambda_2)^m2...(\lambda - \lambda_s)^ms$

$d(\lambda) = \psi(\lambda)q(\lambda)$

$d'(\lambda) = \psi(\lambda)'q(\lambda) + \psi(\lambda)q'(\lambda)$

$\psi(\lambda)q'(\lambda) = 0$

$\psi(\lambda)' = \frac{d}{d\lambda}(\lambda - \lambda_1)^m1[(\lambda - \lambda_1)^m2...(\lambda - \lambda_s)^ms] + (\lambda - \lambda_1)^m1\frac{d}{d\lambda}(\lambda - \lambda_2)^m2(\lambda - \lambda_3)^m3...(\lambda - \lambda_s)^ms$

$\frac{d}{d\lambda}(\lambda - \lambda_1)^m1[(\lambda - \lambda_2)^m2...(\lambda - \lambda_s)^ms] = m1(\lambda - \lambda_1)^(m1-1)(\lambda - \lambda_2)^m2...(\lambda - \lambda_s)^ms = 0$

$(\lambda - \lambda_1)^m1\frac{d}{d\lambda}(\lambda - \lambda_2)^m2(\lambda - \lambda_3)^m3...(\lambda - \lambda_s)^ms = (\lambda - \lambda_1)^m1[\frac{d}{d\lambda}(\lambda - \lambda_2)^m2[(\lambda - \lambda_3)^m3...(\lambda - \lambda_s)^ms] + (\lambda - \lambda_2)^m2\frac{d}{d\lambda}(\lambda - \lambda_3)^m3...(\lambda - \lambda_s)^ms]]$

$(\lambda - \lambda_1)^m1[\frac{d}{d\lambda}(\lambda - \lambda_2)^m2[(\lambda - \lambda_3)^m3...(\lambda - \lambda_s)^ms] = (\lambda - \lambda_1)^m1 m2(\lambda - \lambda_2)^(m2-1)(\lambda - \lambda_3)^m3...(\lambda - \lambda_s)^ms = 0$

If we will continue in the same order finally we get all the derivatives equal to zero.

Comment: Can you include more context in the body of the question?

Comment: The edit you added would be better as an answer. You can answer to your questions.

Answer (score 2):

Read it again.  It only allows derivative up to order multiplicity-1 in the minimum polynomial:
$$d(\lambda_k)=d'(\lambda_k)=\dots=d^{(m_k-1)}(\lambda_k)=0,$$
and the minimal polynomial of $A$ is
$$
\psi(\lambda)=(\lambda-4)(\lambda-2)
$$
so no derivatives is treated here.

Comment: ok it's become more clear, thank you! So in my example there will be no derivatives, because for this minimal polynomial mk=1. For the arbitrary polynomial I just have added comment in the question.